# NSUTF8StringEncoding issue with special characters like "+"

Tags: swift, url, request

I try to make some url request in swift 2.0:

```
func chackAccess(username: String!, password: String!) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

        if responseString != "null" {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
            })
        } else {
            print("shake")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.wrongPassword()
            })
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Everything works great only if I have simple password like a-z 0-9 some chars like )( but problem is with char +.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Certain characters have special meaning within the URL string: `&` separates parameters, `+` stand for whitespace, etc.

Try percentage-escaping it:

```
let charset = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
let username = "auser"
let password = "abc(+.,?/[])123".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(charset)!

let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
// username=auser&password=abc%28%2B%2E%2C%3F%2F%5B%5D%29123
```

`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(charset)` escapes all characters NOT in the `charset`. For example: `+ --> %2B`